# Need to format a CSV

Tags: shell, csv

I have a CSV file with the following values sample shown below

```
"Basic","""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]","","","","",""
```

I need to remove the extra double quotes on certain columns, e.g. 2 and 3

Expected output is below

```
"Basic","21,21","[21,21]","","","","",""
```

How can I achieve this using awk, sed or any other Linux tool?

some more exampled of the files are mentioned below, the values in that column are always in [] with the quotes within the [] that have to be removed.

```
"Basic","""40""","[""40""]","""13F""","[""13F""]","","" 
"Basic","""0""","[""0""]","","","""MCOMB""","[""MCOMB""]"
```

Comment: This can be really easy work for a CSV-aware utility. I like GoCSV, see my complete answer below.

Comment: By removing the internal quotes, you don't just reformat the CSV file but also change the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use a csv parser that understands [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) with quoting and commas embedded in quoted fields and more, which can be a bit more complicated than simple comma-delimited fields.

[miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is a good command-line tool for this, as is [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit).

Or use a csv parsing library for a language like perl or python - e.g. [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) for perl or [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for python.

If you're on Linux, all of these are probably available as packages for whatever distribution you're using.

Comment: not much familiar with miller

Comment: nobody's much familiar with anything before they start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into a CSV-aware tool.  As you've already seen, you can write some very complicated awk and sed and ***still*** get it wrong.  @cas mentioned miller and csvkit, I haven't used those so I cannot say if they can do what you need.

I do use [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv) which is a very simple tool with a number of commands that can help you achieve your goal.

Just taking that one line by itself, the first thing GoCSV needs is a header, so I'll feed that line into its **cap** command to create a dummy header with a default name of 'Col':

```bsh
echo '"Basic","""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]","","","","",""' | \
gocsv cap --default-name Col
```

and I get:

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Col 6,Col 7,Col 8
Basic,"""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]",,,,,
```

*('Col' was appended with unique index numbers for each column)*

You can see the command stripped away the unnecessary empty quotes at the end.  Now, on to the quoted quotes.

I'll take that output and pipe it into the **replace** command where I can specify a regex patten to find, `"`, and a replacement of empty string:

```bsh
echo '"Basic","""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]","","","","",""' | \                                                                  
gocsv cap --default-name Col | \                                   
gocsv replace --regex '"' --repl ''
```

and I get:

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Col 6,Col 7,Col 8
Basic,"21,21","[21,21]",,,,,
```

If you need the header gone, pipe that into **behead**.  Here's the complete pipeline:

```bsh
echo '"Basic","""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]","","","","",""' | \
gocsv cap --default-name Col | \
gocsv replace --regex '"' --repl '' | \
gocsv behead
```

```
Basic,"21,21","[21,21]",,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

I come with a `sed` solution

```
sed -e 's/,"""/,"/g' -e 's/""",/",/g' -e 's/\([^,]\)""/\1/g' -e 's/""\([^,]\)/\1/'
```

which gives

```
"Basic","40","[40]","13F","[13F]","",""
"Basic","0","[0]","","","MCOMB","[MCOMB]"
"Basic","21,21","[21,21]","","","","",""
```

sed command are pretty straightforward

- `'s/,"""/,"/g'` replace `,"""` by `,"` for all occurences `g`
- `'s/\([^,]\)""/\1/g'` find any not comma char `[^,]` and two `"` , remember char `\( \)` and replace by char remembered `\1`

note that a trailling space in end of line will delete last `""`

as @cas pointed out, it would be better in long run to use a csv tool.

Comment: the solution provided wont work in my case as column 2 is  ,""" and column3 is ,"["" .

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to remove all double quotes that are part of the data, i.e., not the double quotes that are part of the CSV format and necessary for quoting embedded quotes, commas, and newlines.

Using `csvformat` from csvkit, and `tr`, to remove the internal quoting on each field:

```bsh
$ cat file
"Basic","""40""","[""40""]","""13F""","[""13F""]","",""
"Basic","""0""","[""0""]","","","""MCOMB""","[""MCOMB""]"
"Basic","""21,21""","[""21"",""21""]","","","","",""
```

```bsh
$ csvformat -Q "'" file | tr -d '"' | csvformat -q "'"
Basic,40,[40],13F,[13F],,
Basic,0,[0],,,MCOMB,[MCOMB]
Basic,"21,21","[21,21]",,,,,
```

The pipeline above first changes the quoting character used in the CSV file from double quotes to single quotes.  The `tr` command deletes all remaining double quotes (part of the data).  The final `csvformat` command converts the data back to using double quotes for quoting.

If you need every field quoted, even the empty ones, add `-U 1` to `csvformat`'s second invocation.  The csvkit utilities, by default, only output quotes for the fields that need it.